# How to start threads in turn in python in a for loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop

I would like to start threads in turns in a for loop, but the next thread should not start until the current one is completed. Please help me with this issue.

I want to achieve this, because I have a GUI, and for each loop a progress bar will appear and run, and the GUI will not be locked (it won't give that ugly "Not Responding" error)

```
for op in ["op1", "op2"]:
    start_thread()

def start_thread():
     display_and_run_progress_bar()
     do_the_operation()
     when_op_is_completed_destroy_progress_bar()
```

Comment: it is not actually multi-threading if you wait for one to finish before starting a new one, is it?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis yes it is very straightforward. I don't have much time to provide sample code

Comment: @Mat so that I will not lock the GUI.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run each op in its own thread, but only one at a time, you'd have to `join` after starting each thread. A `join` tells the main process to wait until the thread is complete before continuing. Going with your pseudocode style:

```
for op in ["op1", "op2"]:
    thread = start_thread(op)
    thread.join()
```

Depending on what threading library you use it'll be a little different, but see for example https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join.

If you run the code above on the main thread though, that'll still lock up the GUI. What I suggest is not creating a new thread for each op, but rather creating a single thread that does each op one by one, like so:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=do_ops, args=[["op1", "op2"]])
thread.start()

def do_ops(ops):
    for op in ops:
        display_and_run_progress_bar()
        do_the_operation()
        when_op_is_completed_destroy_progress_bar()
```

Now all of the ops are run in a single thread that's off the main process so that it doesn't lock the GUI.

Comment: the problem is, the code uses a MySQL connector and connects to database and reads from database. When all threads run simultaneaously they use the same connector and I get `OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')` error.

Comment: OK, but I think in my answer here, you only have one thread running at a time, because `thread.join()` hangs until the thread is complete. You of course have to make `start_thread` return a thread object for this to work.

Comment: I updated my answer to focus more on the problem running this off the main thread so as not to block the GUI.